# make new list of coordinates everytime based on the number of images

Tags: python, list, image

I am generating a list of coordinates (x,y) for each images and there are 10+ images . So for one image the list is generated but when the next image comes in the loop the initial list becomes empty.
So different list for different images.
I tried the below code but the intial image generated list is empty everytime new list pops up

```
CC = []
for k in sorted(glob.glob(path + "*.jpg"),key=os.path.getmtime):
        im = cv2.imread(k)
        orig = im.copy()
        imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
               
        ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
        contours,hierachy=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        c.append(len(contours))
        
        for i in range(len(contours)):            
            M = cv2.moments(contours[i]) 
            if M["m00"] != 0:
               x = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
               y = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
             else:
               x, y = 0, 0

            CC.append((x,y))
oldCC = CC.copy()
```

What i want is below, but each list should be stored they should not be empty or lost.

> for image slice10.jpg list should be CC_1 for image slice11.jpg list
> should be CC_2

Comment: You could provide the additional code this is using? What is `newx` and `newy`? Is `CC = []` in a loop itself?

Comment: they are the coordinates of the centroid of the contours generated

Comment: There is not enough information here to help, the code you have provided if run and `newx` and `newy` are defined, you will get a list with every loops output in `CC`.

Comment: @PacketLoss I have edited the code